# Securely connect MS Access database front-end to MySQL back-end on web host?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

We have a fairly simple M$ Access db, split into front-end (forms, reports, etc.) and back-end (tables).  Currently looking for a way to get the tables with all the critical data off of one desktop and hopefully into a MySQL database on our web host, and be able to connect to it from multiple PCs (still probably only one or two people connecting to it at any give time), and eventually, hopefully, migrate to a web application when time allows.  Many of the examples I've read about people connecting an Access db front-end to a MySQL back-end seem to imply that they are doing so on a LAN, probably behind a firewall, etc.

Is it at all safe to connect a M$ Access front-end to a MySQL backend when that mysql server is running on a remote web host?  Does the ODBC connector take care of encryption?

TIA,

Monte

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The app you describe doesn't seem to me to be the type of scenario that would benefit one iota from hosting on a web server, or conversion to a web application.

Comment: Internal politics.  It's a non-profit club, where the current way of doing things has important data (electronic and otherwise) stashed away in the closets and basements of individuals, not backed up, not secure against any kind of natural disaster, etc.  One person gets sick or passes away or just disaffected in any way, and the group loses all of its data.  I'd rather have it a little more centrally located (web app) where it's backed up regularly by the hosting provider in addition to local copies if we desire, and where if person A moves away or quits, person B or C can pick it up and go.

Comment: do you have a code snippet how you finally realized it. I'm also looking for a connection to a mysql database loacted in the web. I'M connecting with Access 2010. I can connect via putty through the ssh tunnel. but I#m not really aware of vba and how to code it. Thanks Janis

Comment: Sorry, no I don't.  I didn't follow thru with this particular endeavor - mainly because none of the suggested solutions are simple enough for the person doing the data entry to use.  I'm currently looking at something like TeamViewer to remotely access the PC in question (behind routers, NAT, firewalls, etc.) for updates and/or 'fixing' things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use putty to mount a ssh tunnel to your mysql server and redirect the remote mysql port to your machine.

Using putty is pretty straightforward:

Give it your mysql server dns name as the host and go to "Connection/SSH/Tunnels", there you define the local port to connect in the "Source Port" field (e.g. 3307).
In the  the "Destination" field put the dns name of your mysql server followed by a colon and the port mysqld is running in (e.g. mysql.example.org:3306).

Save this as a profile then connect and the remote mysql port will be availbable locally on port 3307.

Just make sure you restrict the user because by default he will have an ssh shell on the server.
Setting up key authentication would also be practical because you won't have to enter a password to connect to the server (but be sure to protect your key on disk by encrypting it).

EDIT: It seems the mysql odbc connector support ssl, you could use that too but I'd personnally choose to use SSH anyway as you will have it already on your mysql server.

Comment: While this might be something 'I' might pull off... I have to wonder if its a good idea for something for use for general non-techy type end users who have never even heard of SSH, ports, tunneling, etc.

Comment: A good application to make interaction easier for end-users is putty-tunnel-manager: http://code.google.com/p/putty-tunnel-manager/ Internally we use putty + ssh keys embedded in a Winform applcation to display a menu, allowing users to choose to which server they want to connect.